# How to go in getView of BaseAdapter to refresh list item? NotifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: android, listview, adapter, getview

When i call notifyDataSetChanged() compiler goes into getCount() but not into getView method.

- I am not adding the new list item, i have just changed some boolean in my existing list item object which i want to use into the if statement in getView method for doing some item-layout changes, but compiler never goes in getView even if i called notifyDataSetChanged()
- for debug i tried to print log of that item boolean into getCount(), and that boolean value is changed!

So my question is: Why compiler not goes into getView method when i do some changes in list item? Any solution for this problem?

Comment: your getCount() must be returning `0`. Post youe code.

Comment: on youtube a user slidenerd has videos on that. Post your code and maybe you can find help here

Comment: to: janki gadhiya - no, getCount() returns 1

Comment: to: janki gadhiya - no, getCount() returns 1, everything seams to be fine with adapter and list but as i said, when notify called compiler goes into getCount but not in getView. Code is very big project and I can't post that, sorry, if you know some other reasons or suggestions I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Changing the list item and notifyDataSetChanged() method was not called from main thread.